# receive_from - An invalid argument was supplied

Tags: boost, udp, client, windows-8.1, boost-asio

I've tried using the example code for a synchronous UDP client from the boost documentation ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4/src.html ), I've only removed the 'sending' part of the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        udp::socket socket(io_service);
        socket.open(udp::v4());

        boost::array<char, 128> recv_buf;
        udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
        size_t len = socket.receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf), sender_endpoint); // Causes the exception "An invalid argument was supplied".

        std::cout.write(recv_buf.data(), len);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I haven't made any other changes to the example code, and I don't see anything wrong with it, so why is it creating the exception? I have no firewall active which could be blocking anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never bound your socket to an endpoint. You need to create a boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint and bind your socket to it. This endpoint represents the ip address and the port that you will be receiving packets on.

See the docs here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/bind.html

Comment: Also note that sending a UDP message automatically binds on the endpoint for you, this might be the reason for which it worked with the "sending part" you cut.